# How can I add chat to an Android app?

Tags: android, sockets, chat

I have an android app, and I would like to allow my users to chat with each other.

Searching google, I found a tutorial on [android socket programming](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/socket-programming/), but it looks quite complicated and requires me to take care of the server side too.

Is there an easier solution that doesn't require me to basically write it all myself?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using one of the free SDK like Scringo ([www.scringo.com](http://www.scringo.com)). 
It is very easy to add - basically all you need is to call

```
Scringo.init(this);
```

at the end of your Activity's onCreate() method.

No need for server side programming at all.

Here's a screenshot of Scringo in action:
[image: Scringo in action]

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest using a WebView and using a node.js / now.js chat!

It's very simple to setup!

Answer (score 0):

Another viable solution is to check xmpp protocol and [asmack library](https://code.google.com/p/asmack/) . I gave it a try a while ago and managed to make it work with gtalk. You can also setup an xmpp server by yourself using their [openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp) server.

Still better than reinvent the wheel.

Comment: can u please answer this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984588/android-chat-using-smack-api-and-talk-goolgle-com-server