# Android chat using Smack API and talk.goolgle.com server

Tags: java, android, smack, asmack

I want to create an android chat application using smack api and **talk.google.com** server but the problem is that when I create a connection to Smack API using gmail id and password and check my user name using "connection.getuser()" my id is showm in following format "anything@gmail.com/Smack_(some smack id)".Now if I send a message from my app using another phone to "anything@gmail.com" it is not recieved but if I send it to "anything@gmail.com/Smack**_**(same smack id)" it is properly recieved.

The smack id being appended is random and changes everytime I connect so it is impossible for me to obtain it by any means and thus message cannot be sent,so how can I overcome this problem.

The code for my ChatActivity is:

```
    package com.prince.chat;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Roster;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterEntry;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.MessageTypeFilter;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.PacketFilter;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Packet;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.util.StringUtils;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ChatActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String HOST = "talk.google.com";
    public static final int PORT = 5222;
    public static final String SERVICE = "gmail.com";
    public static  String USERNAME ;
    public static  String PASSWORD ;

    private XMPPConnection connection;
    private ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    private EditText recipient;
    private EditText textMessage;
    private ListView listview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

        recipient = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.toET);
        textMessage = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.chatET);
        listview = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listMessages);
        setListAdapter();

        Intent i = getIntent();
        USERNAME= i.getStringExtra("email");
        PASSWORD =i.getStringExtra("password");

        // Set a listener to send a chat text message
        Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String to = recipient.getText().toString();
                String text = textMessage.getText().toString();          
                Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity ", "Sending text " + text + " to " + to);
                Message msg = new Message(to, Message.Type.chat);  
                msg.setBody(text);
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.sendPacket(msg);
                    messages.add(connection.getUser() + ":");
                    messages.add(text);
                    setListAdapter();
                }
            }
        });
        connect();
    }



    /**
     * Called by Settings dialog when a connection is establised with 
     * the XMPP server
     */
    public void setConnection(XMPPConnection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
        if (connection != null) {
            // Add a packet listener to get messages sent to us
            PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
            connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
                @Override
                public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                    Message message = (Message) packet;
                    if (message.getBody() != null) {
                        String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message.getFrom());
                        Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity ", " Text Recieved " + message.getBody() + " from " +  fromName);
                        messages.add(fromName + ":");
                        messages.add(message.getBody());
                        // Add the incoming message to the list view
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                setListAdapter();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }, filter);
        }
    }

    private void setListAdapter() {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listitem, messages);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        try {
            connection.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public void connect() {

        final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Connecting...", "Please wait...", false);
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Create a connection
                ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(HOST, PORT, SERVICE);
                XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
                try {
                    connection.connect();
                    Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "[SettingsDialog] Connected to "+connection.getHost());
                } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                    Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "[SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to "+ connection.getHost());
                    Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
                    setConnection(null);
                }
                try {
                    connection.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
                    Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "Logged in as" + connection.getUser());

                    // Set the status to available
                    Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
                    connection.sendPacket(presence);
                    setConnection(connection);

                    Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
                    Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
                    for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {

                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "--------------------------------------");
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "RosterEntry " + entry);
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "User: " + entry.getUser());
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Name: " + entry.getName());
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Status: " + entry.getStatus());
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Type: " + entry.getType());
                        Presence entryPresence = roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());

                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence Status: "+ entryPresence.getStatus());
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence Type: " + entryPresence.getType());

                        Presence.Type type = entryPresence.getType();
                        if (type == Presence.Type.available)
                            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence AVIALABLE");
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence : " + entryPresence);
                    }
                } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                    Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to log in as "+  USERNAME);
                    Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
                    setConnection(null);
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        t.start();
        dialog.show();
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.chat, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: it sounds strange,message will be sent broadcastly, so every client will receive the message,maybe you can post your code.I have wrote similar app,too.

Comment: @user1242027 i have added the code also

Comment: @Prince can you use java smack in android ?i thought i have to use Asmack in order to use Xmpp in android.I am trying to implement gcm Xmpp client in android so that i can send broadcast message to gcm CCS(xmpp).hope you will reply to this comment soon,thanks:)

Comment: @user3523641 I used Asmack ,I have not tried much of GCM yet but for broadcasting you could use Smack based http://quickblox.com/ API or something similar.
The benefit is that all your code will be in JAVA and you don't need to worry about back end.

Comment: thank you vary much for your answer ,can you suggest me is there any way by which i can implement gcm CCS(xmpp) in my android phone,i am working on the code you have wrote above to implement gcm xmpp client in android phone.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the resource id to some known value when you connect, so no generated id will be used (unless the server changes it, which I believe it can do if it wishes).

Comment: user can use another **XMPP client software** like spark when how to handle it? @robin